# How to refactor this code using "Task" in Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

The question is about [this code](https://github.com/Project-Ariel/Polity-Correct/blob/7b5d8f42c64f953b0cf6fb0ce44da0fd85eb73f5/app/src/main/java/com/example/polity_correct/ChooseResultUsers.java#L96) (in an Android application):

```
private Task<QuerySnapshot> getVotesFromDB() {
    res = new int[]{0, 0, 0};   // a private class-member
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Votes")
            .whereEqualTo("proposition_key", curr_proposition.getKey())
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String userChoice = (String) document.get("user_choice");
                        int choice;
                        switch (userChoice) {
                            case "against":
                                choice = 0;
                                break;
                            case "impossible":
                                choice = 1;
                                break;
                            case "agreement":
                                choice = 2;
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + userChoice);
                        }
                        res[choice]++;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

In general, the code reads some lines from a Firestore collection, and applies some "business logic" to them (counting the number of strings from each type). The business logic can, in the future, become much more complicated than just counting. So I am looking for a way to refactor the code, so that the business logic can be written and tested separately from the database. What I would like is to have some function of the form:

```
int[] countVotes(Generator<String> strings) {
     res = new int[3];
     (for String userChoice: strings)  {
          // Update res as above
     }
     return res;
}
```

that can be unit-tested without any need for a database connection. Then, the above function can be refactored as follows:

```
private Generator<String> getVotesFromDB() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Votes")
            .whereEqualTo("proposition_key", curr_proposition.getKey())
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        userChoice = (String) document.get("user_choice");
                        yield userChoice;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

and run something like:

```
countVotes(getVotesFromDB())
```

The problem is, I do not know how to do this with the asynchronous function call. Is there a way to refactor the code in a similar or better way?

Comment: Firebase does not offer synchronous APIs for any of the products in that suite.  Everything is async, and you will need to apply proper async programming techniques to work with it effectively.  You can certainly try to block the thread that performs the query, but that's a really bad idea on Android, as that causes the app to freeze and possibly crash with an ANR.

Comment: @DougStevenson My goal is not necessarily to make the code synchronous - my goal is to separate the logic from the database connection, so that the logic can be unit-tested separately, used with a different database, etc. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Can't you just call `countVotes` from inside the `onCompleteListener` directly? Then you can unit test `countVotes` by itself still.

Comment: @TylerV how can I do this while making `countVotes` accept a collection (or a stream) of strings?

Comment: Why does it need to? Couldn't it just take the string argument you got from the database and update the res class member (returning void)? To test it you'd just call it multiple times to mimic the real use.

Comment: @TylerV this is just an example. In general, the function `countVotes` could be a much more complex function, that computes various statistics on the set of strings. So I want it to get the entire collection of strings.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the results into an array and then process that with a separate method. Then if the processing method is complex it can be unit tested in isolation for various different lists of results.

```java
private void getVotesFromDB() {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Votes")
        .whereEqualTo("proposition_key", curr_proposition.getKey())
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    String userChoice = (String) document.get("user_choice");
                    results.add(userChoice);
                }

                // assign the result to a class member
                res = countVotes(results);

                // do something to signal to the rest of the code
                // that results have been processed (e.g. post to
                // LiveData or call another "showResults" method)
            }
        });
}
```

Then any complicated counting logic can live separate from the firebase calls.

```java
int[] countVotes(ArrayList<String> choices) {
    int[] res = new int[]{0,0,0}; 

    // count the votes

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make "countVotes" return a result (an int[]), rather than update a member variable? It would make it easier to test.

Comment: That depends how you want to use it in the final case, I can add an option that shows how it would work with the version you have posted to the question at least. You can't return values from within the `onCompleteListener`, but if you have it set the result to a class member there you could make the `countVotes` call just return that result

Comment: While this solution works, it may be inefficient if the number of rows in the database is large, since it has to put many strings in an array in memory. Is there a solution that uses something like a stream or a generator, that does not waste memory?

Comment: You already hold an array of the full documents and their data in memory... There are other options with flows and coroutines if you switch to using Kotlin. Or you could adjust your data processing to read in one result at a time and skip the array